# Hiding everything in the iOS navbar, including icons

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad

I've managed to hide the navbar itself, but I want it all gone - charge icon, connection bars, clock - absolutely everything.

I'm aware this may create a 'dead end' for my app, but that's ok for my purposes.

I read [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/78566) that it's apparently not legal. Is that still true?

The app is not for distribution, so I'd still be interested to hear solutions even if Apple doesn't like it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to hide [status bar](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT207354). 
[image]

You can use `prefersStatusBarHidden` property to hide status bar in **Swift 4.2:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

     override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
         return hideStatusBar
     }


     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
     }
}
```

Comment: You assumed correctly! Note to self: Statusbar, not navbar ;-)
Thanks a bunch.